# Error in R: Cosine similarity and MDS

Tags: r

I calculate the cosine similarity with cosine() from the package 'lsa'. Here with three test vectors:

```
d <- data.frame(c(-1,1,0,-1,1,1,-1,1,0),c(-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,0,1),c(0,0,1,0,-1,-1,0,1,-1))
colnames(d) <- c("vector1","vector2","vector3")
d_dist <- cosine(as.matrix(d))
```

Now, I want to do dimensionality reduction with cmdscale and after that plot it as a scatterplot:

```
fit <- cmdscale(d_dist,k=2)

x <- fit[,2]
y <- fit[,1]
plot(x,y)
```

But I always get the warning In cmdscale (d_dist, k = 2): only 0 of the first 2 eigenvalues ​​are> 0 [translated from German] and an empty fit object.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The input should be a distance matrix.  E.g.:

```
d_dist <- 1-d_dist
fit <- cmdscale(d_dist,k=2)

x <- fit[,2]
y <- fit[,1]
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Is it 1-d_dist because cmdscale doesn't work with negative values?

Comment: Cosine is between 0 and 1, negative values don't apply here.  The error message is telling you that the matrix cannot be decomposed (i.e., the matrix is not diagonizable).  Practically speaking, it's because you input a similarity matrix, rather than a distance/dissimilarity matrix.